# GCD - Critical Section/Mutex

Tags: objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Can somebody answer with short example:

How to correctly Lock code part with condition: *if this part is locked by some thread don't hold other threads just skip this part by other threads and keep going.*

Comment: You can use a semaphore. For a "try lock" operation, call `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` with `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` for the timeout parameter. If it returns non-zero, then it timed out, meaning something else holds the lock and you should skip your operation.

Comment: dispatch_semaphore_wait() increase semaphore counter +1 who will decrease this than?

Comment: `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` attempts to **decrease** the semaphore counter. `dispatch_semaphore_wait()` is analogous to locking the lock; `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` is analogous to unlocking it. The semaphore would start with a value of 1 to indicate it's unlocked and a single client can lock it at a time.

Comment: @KenThomases i did an example "in your behalf"

Comment: I'm not sure it correct answer I heard about some NSConditonLock

Answer (score 1):

ok, here is the working example (credit goes to @KenThomases ...)

```
import Dispatch

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
let printQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "print queue")
let group = DispatchGroup()

func longRuningTask(i: Int) {

    printQueue.async(group: group) {
        print(i,"GREEN semaphore")
    }
    usleep(1000)               // cca 1 milisecond
    printQueue.async(group: group) {
        print(i,"job done")
    }
}

func shortRuningTask(i: Int) {
    group.enter()
    guard semaphore.wait(timeout: .now() + 0.001) == .success else { // wait for cca 1 milisecond from now
        printQueue.async(group: group) {
            print(i,"RED semaphore, job not done")
        }
        group.leave()
        return
    }
    longRuningTask(i: i)
    semaphore.signal()
    group.leave()
}

printQueue.async(group: group) {
    print("running")
}

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10, execute: shortRuningTask )
group.wait()
print("all done")
```

and its printout

```
running
0 GREEN semaphore
2 RED semaphore, job not done
1 RED semaphore, job not done
3 RED semaphore, job not done
0 job done
4 GREEN semaphore
5 RED semaphore, job not done
6 RED semaphore, job not done
7 RED semaphore, job not done
4 job done
8 GREEN semaphore
9 RED semaphore, job not done
8 job done
all done
Program ended with exit code: 0
```