# Swift - Prevent two threads to validate a condition at the same time

Tags: swift, multithreading, swift3

Let's say 2 different callback of an API request have to execute this same piece of code :

```
if flag == false {
    flag = true // preventing the whole thing to be called multiple times
    // Do something
    // reset flag to false after 10 sec 
}
```

Sometimes it happens that both threads were so simultaneous, that they both reach "// Do something" instructions.

What is the proper swifty way to resolve this case ?

Comment: you can use [operationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue)

Comment: Could you provide a code example I don't see how this helps ?

Comment: The first question you should ask is "Why does this happen at all?". Callbacks are usually per task/request. Do your callbacks have a shared mutable state and why? Is the "do something" idempotent? Is the order important? If the order is not important and the "do something" is idempotent you can use an operation queue to  execute "do something" only once.

Comment: don't use any 'flag' for synchronisation of your code. check Dispatch framework and use some 'native' synchronisation provided by this framework. try to be inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/44537840/3441734 which demonstrate the same thing (avoid to execute some part of a code, if the code is running and simply avoid to execute it)

Comment: This has quite a lot on various thread sync primitives https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html

Comment: "What is the proper swifty way" ... There isn't going to be a particularly Swifty way of dealing with this, as Swift does not yet get to this level of detail. You just need to synchronize this code somehow (e.g. run it on a serial queue, run it with barrier on concurrent queue, synchronize with some mechanism, e.g. `NSLock`). If you want to make your synchronization process to have a Swifty feel, you can have some generic type that wraps this synchronization mechanism.